# How can I connect to a DFS share on a Windows 2016 Server?

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba

My company host our data on a Windows Server 2016. I am running Xubuntu (version 15.04) and cannot get connected to our share using the `mount` command.

This is an example of command I unsuccessfully tried (I wanted to mount the folder`Folder4`under`Test_mnt`in the example below):

```
sudo mount -v -t cifs //domain.adress.org/dfs/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4 /home/alkalyzer/Test_mnt -o username=domain/myusername,domain=domain.adress.org,rw
```

While doing so (after having provided my password at the prompt), I received the following error message :

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

And this is what is written in`/var/log/syslog`:

```
Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

I followed different methods to try to get this to work:

1. Changing`workgroup`to`workgroup = DOMAIN` in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`
2. Adding`wins support = yes` in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`
3. Adding both`client min protocol = SMB2`and`client max protocol = SMB3`in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`
4. Adding these two lines in`/etc/request-key.conf`:

   ```
   create cifs.spnego  *   *       /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -t %k
   create  dns_resolver    *   *       /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
   ```

I can connect to this share by using a file-browser (Thunar or Nautilus) but I cannot browse the folder contained in`/run/user/1000/gvfs`which corresponds to the remote folder (`ls` indicates that all permissions and ownerships are filled by question mark for this folder).

I can also connect to this share with `smbclient` with this command:

```
smbclient //domain.adress.org/dfs/ -Udomain/myusername -Whdomain.adress.org -D Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4
```

How can I mount these remote folders with the `mount` command?

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution [in this blog post](https://vlkan.com/blog/post/2015/01/08/smb-mount-troubleshoot/)

Install the `keyutils` package.

```
sudo apt-get install keyutils
```

Now I am able to mount the dfs share without a servername:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //mydfsdomain/namespaceroot/sharedfolder /mnt/sharedfolder -o credentials=/etc/cred.file
```